# Mirror modifier. Mirrored half is not aligned, but rotated

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

[image]

I was working on my character's hand when I realized half of the body was suddenly deleted. I am trying to recreate the other half, but it just won't mirror properly in the center. I tried moving the origin to the 3D cursor while it was completely centered, but the mirror modifier is still applied at an angle.

Comment: Has the rotation been applied?

Comment: how do i apply rotation? and what to?

Comment: Ctrl+A > Rotation

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your problem, but your normals look like they are inverted.

Answer (score 5):

What you are seeing is caused by not applied transforms, specifically rotation. Since the mirror modifier mirrors along the local axis by default, it is not mirroring as desired. What you can do is **apply the rotation** using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Rotation*. This will set the local axis orientation the same as the global axis, and should solve your issue.

[image]