# Mirror Modifier isn't working correctly its offset?

Tags: modifiers, mirror

Hi guys i'm having a small issue here trying to get my mirror modifier to work, I believe it has something to do with the origin point but being new to blender I don't have the know how to fix this problem. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be incredible.

Thanks guys.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B88dKYvqd3wOM1hkbGlYNkhPUk0/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: I can't look at the file right now but did you apply rotation?

Comment: This question has many duplicates, for example [one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72697/mirror-modifier-doesnt-work) and [two](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33400/mirror-modifier-doesnt-work-properly). Please do a search before posting a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mesh has been rotated in object mode:

[image]

To apply its rotation (i.e. making it retain its orientation while havin the angles all set to zero) use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Read:[Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

When you do that, the viewport's axes will match the object internal coordinates and the `Mirror` modifier will work as you'd expect (you may need to change the axis you're currently using for mirroring)

[image]

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thank you for your help. When the wait time has finished i'll mark this as correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

your mesh is rotated, the mirroring is being done on its local axis.

Apply your rotation with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select rotation.