# Why aren't these sections mirroring properly?

Tags: mirror

[image]

For whatever reason certain parts of the model won't mirror properly? Like most of the joints and segments mirror fine, and the middle arms mirror fine, but the shields and hands and wrists on the top arms and bottom arms mirror all over the place that don't make sense for x,y or z.

Does someone know why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Please add some screenshots to better illustrate your issue. Without that, it's just guessing.

Comment: Sorry about that, the picture didn't upload the first time, but it's up now

Comment: Hello again :). Try applying your object's rotation through *Object > Apply > Rotation*.

Comment: It seems to work! Thank you! Does object apply rotation reset something?

Comment: That's right, it's explained here :) https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/84805/78972