# Mirror modifier creates two tails on model?

Tags: animation, armature, mirror

I am trying to apply a mirror onto my Cheetah model, in edit mode the resting position is how I want the mirror to be applied, however, when it is in object mode, the resting position is that of the animation and the mirror is applied to that position. How can I apply the mirror to the position of edit mode? 
 How do I fix this? 
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84804

Comment: Indeed that seems better, thanks